# Help mapping Domain model with EF4.1 fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, fluent-interface

I'm new to EF and the fluent API.  My DBA decided he wanted to map the "primary" citizenship of a person with an Is_Primary flag in the citizenships table.  So our DB looks something like this:

```
**Person Table**
Person_Id    int           identity  (PK)
First_Name   nvarchar(30)
...

**Citizenship_Table**
Citizenship_Person_Id  int identity  (PK)
Person_Id              int
Country_Code           char(2)
Is_Primary             byte
...

**Country_Table**
Country_Code     char(2)  (PK)
Country_Name     varchar(30)
...
```

I really don't want the Is_Primary flag in my domain model.  Instead, I want my domain to look something like this:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Country> Citizenships {get; set;}
   public Country PrimaryCitizenship {get; set;}
}

public class Country
{
   public int Code {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way to map this scenario?

Comment: Is the database table structure written in stone? If yes and you cannot change it, I believe there is no hope to map this. It's a many-to-many relation between `Person` and `Country`, right? Then you would even need to make the join table ("Citizenship_Table") to an entity in your model because of this "Is_Primary" flag and create two one-to-many relations instead of a singe many-to-many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to map your domain model proposal to the given table structure. In my opinion it's also wrong - from the domain viewpoint - to introduce an `Is_Primary` flag into the Citizenship table (which is basically a join table between `Person` and `Country`).

The domain says that a person can have *one* primary citizenship (or perhaps none) but never *many*. This is not correctly expressed in the table structure: The `Is_Primary` column could be set for more than one country for a given person. It's also difficult to change the primary citizenship for a person because you would have to search for all entries in the citizenship table belonging to that person if there is another country marked as primary, then reset this flag before you set the flag for the new country.

This is correctly expressed in your model which means that the `Person` should have a foreign key to the `Country` table (either required or optional). Changing the primary citizenship would only require to set this FK to another value. Duplicate primary flags are impossible in this model.

If you change the table structure accordingly to the following ...

```
**Person Table**
Person_Id                int           identity  (PK)
First_Name               nvarchar(30)
PrimaryCountry_Code      char(2)                 (FK to Country table)
...

**Citizenship_Table**
Person_Id                int                     (PK)
Country_Code             char(2)                 (PK)

**Country_Table**
Country_Code             char(2)                 (PK)
Country_Name             varchar(30)
...
```

... a mapping to your model would be possible:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .HasColumnName("Person_Id");

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .Property(p => p.Name)
    .HasColumnName("First_Name")
    .HasMaxLength(30);

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Citizenships)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(a => {
        a.MapLeftKey("Person_Id");
        a.MapRightKey("Country_Code");
        a.ToTable("Citizenship");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.PrimaryCitizenship) // or .HasRequired(...)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("PrimaryCountry_Code"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
    .HasKey(c => c.Code)
    .Property(c => c.Code)
    .HasColumnName("Country_Code")
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
    .HasMaxLength(2)
    .IsFixedLength()
    .IsUnicode(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
    .Property(c => c.Name)
    .HasColumnName("Country_Name")
    .HasMaxLength(30)
    .IsUnicode(false);
```

Not a solution to your problem, but some food for discussion with your DBA.

Comment: I whole heartedly agree with you, which is why I did not want the Is_Primary flag included in my domain model.  Since the DBA doesn't want to change his design, I was trying to figure out a way to make this work.  Thank you very much for your input though!  That is pretty much the same conclusion I came to but needed some confirmation to be sure I wasn't missing some feature of EF and fluent API that might allow that to work.

Comment: @RHarris: Unfortunately there are (theoretically) much more scenarios which can *not* be mapped than scenarios which can. "Impedance mismatch" between object world and relational world is still there and will probably never go away completely. That's the reason why DBAs should talk together with application/domain model developers these days when it comes to using an ORM. And the leadership should be in the hand of the model designer which have to use the ORM successfully. If a DBA designs tables alone in his relational world chances are big that it comes to unmappable trouble - in my opinion.